# How can I reduce if-else statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement

My code:

```
if(!"".equals(et1.getText().toString())){
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(!"".equals(et2.getText().toString())){
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(!"".equals(et3.getText().toString())){
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(!"".equals(et4.getText().toString())){
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(!"".equals(et5.getText().toString())){
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter text5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

//Totally 13 fields, so this will go near 13 checking. So just I want to know is there any possibility to check with one statement and find which filed is leaved as empty.

Thank you.

Comment: why is this tagged c++ or c?

Comment: I think instead of showing different Toast messages for all fields you can just use a single message. Like "Please fill all fields." Then you can write the condition in one line using && operator.

Comment: id advice you put a star against each field that is necessary, compare all the values inside one if statement using || and then display a common message!

Comment: and loop until you get all input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it in a `List`

```
for (EditText et : etList) {
    if(!"".equals(et.getText().toString()))
}
```

Comment: I didn't ask this type of answer, But this one reduce my code length. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Store the objects (et1, 2, 3, ...) in an array, and then iterate on it.

Comment: While it works, i think it is against the OOP approach. When you need to use many `if` statements like OP, then consider polymorphism to solve the task.

Comment: I just want to check within one execution, Anyway thanks for your help. +1 added.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add a `textwatcher` to your fields. see the snippet below.

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private GenericTextWatcher() {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       if(editable.toString().equals(""))
       {
           Toast.makeText(UrActivity.this, "ur toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
}
```

and then register `textlistener`.

`editext.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher());`

validating it on actual keypress will be faster then clubbing the checking later.

Comment: I just want to check within one execution for all `EditText`, Anyway thanks for your help. +1 added.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement view classes (in [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) notation) that represent the necessary controls and would use [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) to avoid these if statements.

**UPDATE:**

As I understand there is shown an input validation mechanism. I would do the following.

My explanation could be more general than it is expected for your particular task. But I think it will help you in future. And please note I am not too proficient with Android API, so you may need to adjuct my references to some Android API classes, for instance a class, that represents a field.

So, the first step. Declare the field prototype:

```
abstract FieldPrototype extends AndroidFieldClass {

    /**
    * Checks field contents and returns true if field is ok, otherwise shows popup validation message and returns false.
    * @return see method description.
    */
    public abstract boolean checkField();

}


class Et1Field extends FieldPrototype {

    private String value;

    public Et1Field() {
        super();
        // your initialization code here
    }

    public boolean checkField() {
        if (value == null || "".equals(value)) {
            // show validation message specific for Et1Field class instance.
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

// do the same steps for Et2Field .. Et13Field if those fields are different, 
// and implement specific validation functionality for every kind of a field.
```

In your screen class keep an array of all fields displayed on this screen. On save event in your screen, send `save` event to all field instances.
Every field will invoke it's own checkField() method and validate it's own contents, without showing particular field implementation outside.
And if a field validation failed you just stop and let a user to correct a field contents.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please, Because I didn't get you.

Comment: @Gunaseelan I have added an update, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

make one function to check blank and called it once like this...

```
    checkBlank(et1.getText().toString()), 1);
checkBlank(et2.getText().toString()), 2);
checkBlank(et3.getText().toString()), 3);..and so on
```

here is function..

```
private void checkBlank(String edt,int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(edt.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter text"+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Godd Luck:)

Comment: your code and posted question is executes as same you are just written in one method no more change..